# Get $P(W^2 > Z > t) = \frac {1}{3} - t + \frac {2}{3} t^{3/2}$ where $t \in (0,1)$

Tags: statistics, random-variables, independence, uniform-distribution

So we should show that $P(W^2 > Z > t) = \frac {1}{3} - t + \frac {2}{3} t^{3/2}$   where $t \in (0,1)$  when $Z, W$ are independent $U[0,1]$ random variables.

Comment: "We" includes you, as well. What are your efforts to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you certain the listed answer is correct? When I solve the problem, I get something with two terms, neither of which is constant or a multiple of $t$.

Comment: @Math1000 yes the answer should be correct. Regarding my efforts, as they're limited to the material we're getting to study and easy examples we're given, they don't match any ability someone's else have on the subject. Also given the time constraints I can't find a way to answer this question other than posting it here. I know I should show some work on it, but all I can do is tell you what formulas I know from the slides provided. I'm really sorry for that, I'll delete the question if it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

Probability is equal to the area when we integrate the pdf, hence the task that I give you is to find the area of the shaded region. Possibly by integration.

[image]

Comment: I know that Probability of X greater or equal to something is the integral of the pdf. In this case we have two inequalities. Shouldn’t I use double integration in that case? And do I get the pdf knowing that $Z$ and $W$ have a uniform distribution?

Comment: A single integral sufficies though it is possible to do it via double integration. The pdf is $1$ on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ which is just the area.